# Is a gametophyte a spore?

Tags: botany

The male and female gametophytes are pollen and embryo sacs respectively. I wondered if they are spores as their brethren are meiospores.

Answer (score 1):

#### No.

But close.  Very close.  Basically, a gametophyte is a spore that has / is undergoing mitotic division.  Therefore, it is still haploid, having not undergone fertilization yet, but it is no longer a dormant, unicellular spore; it's passed into the new phase of gametophyte.

The gametophyte produces sexual organs which produce the gametes that will actually be used in fertilization.  Two gametes fuse, at which point, a diploid cell is produced (called a zygote, just as in animals).

[image]

The meiospores are the spores you see in the picture on the far left: they are dormant, unicellular, haploid spores, which will turn into the gametophytes.  (meio + spores; spores that have undergone meiosis)

---

#### Sources:

- [*Meiospore*, Biology Online](https://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Meiospore)
- [*Gametophyte*, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gametophyte)
- [*Plant Life Cycles*, Developmental Biology, 6th ed.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9980/)
- [*Spore*, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore)